# Accessing a csv file with D3 inside meteor

Tags: csv, d3.js, meteor

I had successfully rendered a HTML table displaying data from a csv file using D3, but when I moved the same code into a meteor project, I'm having problems. The data object being passed into the callback for d3.csv() is picking up the HTML file 1 line at a time instead of the csv data. This only happens when trying to run it in meteor.

My code is set up like this:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  d3.csv("data/dataset.csv", function(data) {
    console.dir(data);

    // do stuff
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  // do other stuff
}
```

Any ideas on why this might be happening?

Comment: try placing your csv file in `public/data/data.csv`

Comment: Askhat or OP can you please post as an answer and accept. This will improve the search results in SO.

Answer (score 3):

(Simply copying Ashkat's comment as per @booyaa's request in comments:)

try placing your csv file in `public/data/data.csv`