# In Meteor, how can I import data from a .tsv file to use in a d3.js chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, meteor

When I call a function like the following, the data object comes out undefined, and the chart won't render.  How can I import this data using Meteor?

UPDATE:
I'm trying out `deps.autorun...` as per [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23564449/integrating-d3-with-meteor-trying-to-draw-pie-charts) and [@ethaan's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3961546/ethaan) answer below.  This got my chart to render.

**However**, oddly enough, it renders with completely the wrong dataset.  Very interesting...
Here's the link to the current state of my project on github: https://github.com/goodwordalchemy/Reactive-line-graph-with-meteor/tree/master/barChart_pt2-meteor
Check out waffles.tsv (changed name to distinguish from old file named data.tsv, which d3 seems to be loading).

And here is a screenshot of what's getting rendered:
[image: But is a screenshot of what's getting rendered]

UPDATE II: As per [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821786/accessing-a-csv-file-with-d3-inside-meteor) I moved my data file into the public folder, and I am able to render my chart in the browser. However, The chart is not reactive.  If I change the .tsv file, the data in the chart does not change....

---

```
Template.d3chart.rendered = function(){

    // chart attributes and scale are defined up here...

    var chart = d3.select(".chart")

    d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
      // callback function
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Template.d3chart.rendered = function(){ 
    // chart attributes and scale are defined up here...
    Tracker.autorun(function(){
     var chart = d3.select(".chart")
    d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
      // callback function
    }
 })

}
```

Typo on rendered?, render dosn't exists

Comment: Sorry about that.  That's just a typo in this minimal reproduction of the problem.

Comment: That worked, but now I have a stranger problem... check out the edit to my question if you're interested

Comment: wich data you want to load, i see on the jsFile, you have `var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];`, so for me its ok, what data you want to load to chart?, the `.tsv` from `/public` folder? btw if my answer help you will be nice to mark as accepter or up voted,

Comment: forgive my newbishness...I didn't properly commit and push the project to github.  I've got the correct version up now.  I want to upload the tsv file in the project.  Thing is, it's not reactive yet...Any ideas?